# IE8 display:none; to display:block; causes div to overlap footer?

Tags: javascript, html

I have a form with errors that appear above it that look like

`<div class="form-error" id="optin_error" style="display: none; ">You must opt-in to participate.</div>`

And a form inside a `<form>` with a bunch of inputs inside of `divs`... nothing really out of the ordinary.

But I have javascript validation on my field with turns the form-error from `display:none;` to `display:block;` which resizes the container field fine. The problem lies in the fact there is a footer (also inside a div) that does not move down. If I open up IE8 developer and look at the main container (that wraps everything) it also does not extend. If I for example uncheck the main container width style and then recheck it, it fixes everything.

Is there a way to force IE8 to "resize" their divs when an element inside a div turns from display:none; to display:block;

PS. There is no funny css, no floats, no absolute positioning, nothing that would cause this...

Form Error Block CSS

```
.form-error {
    color: #EB1F25;
}
```

Footer Block CSS

```
.footer-wrapper {
    border-top: 1px solid #000000;
    margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
}
.footer-wrapper .links {
    width: 960px;
}
```

**After some investigating it seems the `inline-block` attribute on the container is causing the issue.**

Comment: show us your mark-up and the rest of your css and we might be able to help you (a www.jsfiddle.net example is highly recommended)

Comment: ..also, don't use inline styles. You have set an ID for the error box, so make use of it and put `#optin_error { display: none; }` in your stylesheet

Comment: can you show us your entire code ? maybe jsbin will be nice.

Comment: Give some specific `Height`. may be it will solve your problem.

Comment: The problem seems to be the fact the main container has inline-block.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Ended up being an issue with display:inline-block; element not resizing. Changing to float worked.

Answer (score 0):

try givin the width to the wrapper. remember the footer should be inside your main wrapper, Also give a height other divs... min-height or something similar.

```
.footer-wrapper {
border-top: 1px solid #000000;
margin: 30px 0 10px 0;
width: 960px;
}
.footer-wrapper .links {
  width : 100px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

It's hard to tell what exactly is making the problems. But you can test out some of this tips I suggest you to try:

If your `.form-error` is showing up before (above) the actual `<form ...></form>`, then try to insert a `<br clear="all"/>` tag between those two blocks. If not, add `clear:all` to `<form ...>` and `width:100%` to `.form-error`.

If not, add `position:relative` and `overflow:hidden` first to the `.form-error`, if not helps, add it to `<form...>` too.

As already said, will be much easier if we could see your entire code, try to use jsbin with your entire **css** and **html** source code, because IE is very strict in html rendering.